# Can you make JSP to crash on undeclared variables?

Tags: java, jsp

We've noticed that undeclared variables in JSP can cause really bad performance.

Look at the following sample code:

```
<c:if test="...">
    <c:set var="isSaleCategory" value="true"/>
</c:if>

<c:forEach items="${ARTICLES}" var="article" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${not empty articlePrice && (!isSaleCategory)}">
```

The code took 5-6 seconds to process and return a result.

If we initialize the variable first, the execution time drops to a few milliseconds:

```
<c:set var="isSaleCategory" value="false"/>

<c:if test="...">
    <c:set var="isSaleCategory" value="true"/>
</c:if>

<c:forEach items="${ARTICLES}" var="article" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${not empty articlePrice && (!isSaleCategory)}">
```

Now, we dont mind so much adding this code to initialize the variables, but the tricky part is finding them... On pages without loops we wont see the second+ response times, but under heavy load, of course this adds up to unnecessary load.

Is there a way to make JSP processing fail when it stumbles on uninitialized variables like above?

Comment: are there no NPE's? Looks more like some hind of error handling on second test where `isSaleCategory` can be not set due to first test failure. What if you would add NullPointer check as a OR condition in second test?`( isSaleCategory is null || !isSaleCategory)`

Comment: How big is your article collection? Seems strange that variable coercion should be that expensive.

Comment: @Antoniossss JSP is quite forgiving (which is the core problem in this case) and don't throw any exceptions for these scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why it's slow when accessing undeclared variables is that the ELResolvers dig very deep to try and find the variable.

See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jsp-api/8.0.15/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ScopedAttributeELResolver.java#58

Many ClassNotFoundExceptions are thrown when trying alot of non declared variables which takes a lot of time.

One way to solve this is to write a custom ELResolver that simply puts the variable as resolved if not found in page scope with the value null, this prevents the framework from digging any deeper.

```
private static class NullOnMissingVariableELResolver extends ELResolver
{
    /** {@inhericDoc} */
    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) 
    {
        if (base == null && property != null) 
        {
            String key = property.toString();
            PageContext page = (PageContext) context.getContext(JspContext.class);
            Object result = page.findAttribute(key);

            if (result == null)
            {
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This of course comes with some caveats, if you have templates that makes use of these special class lookups, they won't work!

Comment: Great suggestion! In development mode we can set the ELResolver to throw an exception and fix unset variables.

Comment: Found the root cause: https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#JavaServer_Pages_2.3

Answer (score 0):

I found out more about the issue and it seems it appeared in Tomcat 8:
https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#JavaServer_Pages_2.3

Another solution is to prepend the variables with the scope, so instead of:

```
${isSaleCategory}
```

use

```
${requestScope.isSaleCategory}
```

Though this means a lot of change to jsp files, so Marcus' answer with a customer ELResolver is pretty neat to find those occurances.